# Rolling Average Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I am trying to find an average function that is able to automatically update when data is added in the row.

For Example: If I have to phases of data 1 & 2. 1, has less data the 2 how do I find the average function no matter the amount of data.

I have done so much research and I can not find anything

Comment: Please post a screenshot with before and after data, i.e. what you have in the beginning and what you need using the formula, preferably a copiable data using the [Markdown_Table_Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

`=AVERAGE(1:1)` - this will give the average of all populated numeric cells in row 1. Adjust the numbers as necessary for different rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question: you mention rolling average and in top of that you say that you want it to be filled in when a new value is added. All those things are quite obvious in Excel. There's just a part which might be confusing, and that's the part where the averages should not be calculated when no values are filled in, so I come up with the following formula (first to be filled in in B6):

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A6)),AVERAGE(A2:A6),"")
```

The rolling average is the `AVERAGE(A2:A6)`: it calculates the average of five subsequent cells in column "A". When you drag this down, you see that it changes into:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A7)),AVERAGE(A3:A7),"")
```

, which is again calculating the average of the last five values in column "A".
However, there's an issue: when you drag this down over the whole "B" column, you'll get wrong values for the cases where the value in column "A" is not filled in, hence the `IF(NOT(ISBLANK` trick: it blocks the filling of the "B" column if there's no value in "A", and you end up with something like:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?